# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, standard c library "open" on iphone?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, exc-bad-access

Pretty straightforward question,

no matter what I do the app crashes on attempting to call open(), below is a part of the code that is relevant. filename is not a garbage value, and contains an absolute path to the file. This fails on the device and the simulator.

printf of filename returns:

> /Users/programmingstation7/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3/Applications/E2BD16DB-FFBA-45D2-B425-96C981380B85/Documents/issue2.zip

relevant backtrace:

```
#0 0x002132dc in open () 

#1 0x000ddcec in -[ExternalZipInstaller
unzipTheFile] (self=0x68a8d60, _cmd=0x1483f3) at
ExternalZipInstaller.mm:261
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

#ifndef O_BINARY
#define O_BINARY 0
#endif
- (void) unzipTheFile
{
    BOOL success = YES;
    const char* filename = [self.zipName UTF8String];
    open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace?  What happens if you `printf("%s\n", filename)` right before calling `open`?

Comment: And what happens if you hardcode the correct filename as a string literal?

Comment: It's not very helpful, printf:"/Users/programmingstation7/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/E2BD16DB-FFBA-45D2-B425-96C981380B85/Documents/issue2.zip" backtrace: `#0  0x002132dc in open ()
#1  0x000ddcec in -[ExternalZipInstaller unzipTheFile] (self=0x68a8d60, _cmd=0x1483f3) at ExternalZipInstaller.mm:261`

Comment: I've tried hard-coding as well, same error.

Comment: You need to capture the file descriptor returned by `open()`, don't you?

Comment: It is generally best to add the extra information to the question (you can edit your own question) rather than just adding a comment.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll do that... I'm not capturing it just because I want to test the function itself crashing, which I encountered previously. If I do capture it, still the error happens.

Comment: Unless you're doing something crazy like overwriting the machine code where the code for `open` resides (which would require changing the memory protections, and I don't think that's even possible to do on an iOS device), that should not be happening.  If you pass an invalid pointer to `open`, it should fail with `errno` set to `EFAULT`.  In the gdb prompt, what are the outputs of `disas open` and `info reg`?

Comment: I'm starting to understand the general problem area; I started a new project and open() works just fine; I'm linking to a few other static libraries/dependencies and I figure there's some kind of interference going on. Would it be possible for an objectiveC method called "open" to overwrite the fcntl one? Also, I'm not quite sure how to pass those commands in xcode.

Comment: Holy crap I found it, another developer made a static var named "open" which overwrote it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes, it might be possible for another library to define a function called `open` that overwrites the standard one, if the standard one is defined as a weak symbol.  To type those commands into Xcode, find the gdb console window in the debugger, it should say something like `(gdb) ` at the very bottom of it.  Put your cursor there and type those commands into it.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBHCCED) for the UTF8String method of NSString has the following note:

> The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object
>   would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store
>   it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is
>   created.

I think you need to copy the resulting string into your own buffer instead of just pointing to it. The ObjC garbage collector could be deleting your string from under you. Try this instead:

```
const char filename[MAX_PATH];
strcpy(filename, [self.zipName UTF8String], MAX_PATH);
open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
```

Comment: That whould only be true if he intended to use the filename at a later point. At the point of the call to open, the filename buffer is valid and will be so at least until the end of the method call (just like an autorelease).